# PopUp Views in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to implement a PopUp view similar to the one apple provides for the iPad but for the iPhone. I've done a lot of reading and research and it seems that to do this there's a lot of manual work that has to be done and a lot of configurations for my view. I've seen a lot of apps that use these types of popups either ones that appear from the button or appear in the middle. Any ideas on how to implement this?

I found this library https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController and it seems to cover everything I need but I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way to do it.

Comment: I offer this lib, works great! I used this lib for my two project. https://github.com/Backelite/MaryPopin

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for :) :) 

A few questions though if you don't mind. I was thinking of either using a third party class like the one you mentioned or creating something from scratch. What do you think?

Comment: My opinion is, just use:) No need to reinvent the wheel. They have developed really good lib. Just use and maybe contribute on GitHub:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about UIPopovers, as standard Apple doesn't allow popover's on iPhones, they are an iPad and OS X only tool. You could use an UIAlertView or a custom UIView to display extra information.

Comment: I was referring to implementing similar to what Apple provides for the iPad. The idea is to show a small view that appears at the button of the screen to provide some functionality. Similar to ActionSHeets but with some buttons , etc.

Comment: If it's just a few buttons to provide some user choice I usually go with a UIAlertView. If you really want more control over the position and look of the view then it's not too difficult to customise UIView.